# How do you include a plugin in Compass (through Assetic) for Symfony2?

Tags: plugins, symfony-2.1, compass-sass, assetic

I have installed the compass-rgbapng plugin, but am struggling to to include the plugin for use in Symfony2.

I need to add the `require "rgbapng"` to the compass config file, but I am unsure how to do this through Symfony2.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like that in `app/config/config.yml` should helps:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    filters:
        compass:
            plugins:
                - rgbapng
```

Answer (score 1):

Assetic's compass filter looks for a parameter called `assetic.filter.compass.plugins`:

So you can do this in your `app/config/config.yml`:

```
parameters:
    assetic.filter.compass.plugins:
        - rgbapng
```