# How to require 'breakpoint' in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, sass, twig, compass-sass, breakpoint-sass

The project uses Symfony2, Twig, Compass, Sass and Breakpoint. We've installed Breakpoint, but have no idea where to write the instruction for compass (require 'breakpoint'), because we don't use config.rb. What is the way to turn on Breakpoint?

Comment: We find the answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160854/how-do-you-include-a-plugin-in-compass-through-assetic-for-symfony2

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoint is a Compass extension and requires a touch of Ruby to function properly. In order to use it, you must be using the Ruby implementation of Sass and Compass. As Sass 3.3 is in the RC phase as of this weekend at SassConf, Breakpoint will soon be updated to work without the need of Ruby, but it will then require a Sass compiler that is functionally equivalent to Sass 3.3 ([libsass](http://libsass.org/), for instance, is not yet compatible with Sass 3.2 and therefore would be incompatible) in order to run. I know of no alternative-language compilers for Sass that have full Sass 3.3 support (or for that matter, Sass 3.2 support).

If you are compiling through the Ruby Compass gem (i.e. not simply using Compass's mixins, but using the full Compass gem which is both a set of mixins and an extension framework. Most Compass wrappers I know of (for instance, [Grunt Contrib Compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/)) provide a way for you to pass required gems into the compiler. Figure out Compass gets called. If it doesn't have a way for you to explicitly add required gems, see if you can pass `-r breakpoint` into the `compass compile` call.